# How do I add a backtick to a regex on a range of characters matching in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Imagine I have the String

```
asdf-'`
```

Which I want to validate as ok using a regex.

ie alphabetic characters, hyphens, apostophes and backticks.

Everything works except for the backtick in the following example:

html:

```
Type something here: <input type="text" id="in">

<div id="out"></div>
```

javascript:

```
var $out = $("#out");
$("input").keyup(function () {
    if (/^[a-zA-Z ' -`]+$/.test(this.value))
        $out.text("Regex tested OK");
    else
        $out.text("Regex tested not OK");
});
```

result:

```
Type something here: asdf-'`
Regex tested not OK
```

My question is: **How do I add a backtick to a regex on a range of characters matching in JavaScript?** 
(The other regex questions on backticks don't appear to address this question).

Comment: Works for me: `/^[a-zA-Z ' -\`]+$/.test("asdf-'\`") == true`

Comment: Try it here http://jsfiddle.net/a4vGA/

Comment: Did you want to allow spaces?

Comment: Yeah, works for me. Your fiddle is missing the tilde, though. Here's the update with the code you've pasted above: http://jsfiddle.net/a4vGA/57/

Comment: @rgthree - your example seems to have broken the regex - it now matches integers

Comment: @hawkeye Ah, gotcha. Thought that would work. Anyway, just escape the dash. `/^[a-zA-Z' \-\`]+$/`. Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/a4vGA/61/

Comment: That's it - can you expand that into an answer?

Comment: @hawkeye sure. I've made a more detailed answer  for you (and also a lot more detail why your pasted expression actually does work which was interesting).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Your Answer(s)

**First off, the regular expression does actually work,** just not how you think. *I'll get to that later, under the horizontal rule below.*

Your issue is not with the backtick, but with the hyphen before it. Since you are using a hyphen to create your `(a-z)` and `(A-Z)` ranges then you must be aware that the hyphen *can be* a special character within a "character class" (the name for the characters contained in the square brackets) to create a range between two valid characters. However, your last three characters are also creating a range between a space and the backtick `` ( -`) `` instead of searching for the hyphen and backtick explicitly.

So, if you want to look for a hyphen specifically you need to do one of the following:

1. Don't put it between two valid characters. This means, place it at the beginning, at the end, after another range, etc.
2. Escape it.

Here are some examples, and a fixed up jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/a4vGA/63/):

```
// Personally, I like #2. Escaping the hyphen just reads much nicer to me:
/^[a-zA-Z' \-`]+$/  // The searchable hyphen char is escaped, breaking the range.

// But any of these all make the searchable hyphen work without escaping:
/^[a-zA-Z' `-]+$/  // The searchable hyphen char is last
/^[-a-zA-Z' `]+$/  // The searchable hyphen char is first
/^[a-z-A-Z' `]+$/  // The searchable hyphen char is between two ranges and, 
                   // therefore, cannot create a range
/^[a-zA-Z-' `]+$/  // The searchable hyphen char is after a range and and, 
                   // therefore, cannot create a range
// etc.
```

**Any of the above will answer your question. You can stop reading here!**

---

### Why did it work before?

Your problem was interesting since your pasted regular expression in your question **does actually work** with your pasted string `` asdf-'` ``.

```
/^[a-zA-Z ' -`]+$/.test("asdf-'`") // true; but not why you may think.
```

*(**Note:** Your [jsfiddle from your comments simply had a typo](http://jsfiddle.net/a4vGA/) from your pasted regex in the question accidentally omitting the backtick which was causing it to fail with your test string.)*

So then, as we covered above, if the hyphens for this expression are creating three sets of ranges and NOT searching explicitly for the hyphen character, why does it still work? Let's break down the expression to see what's going on.

Your pasted expression `` ^[a-zA-Z ' -`]+$ `` will match any series of characters from the start of your line to the end that match:

- `(a-z)` as a range, or any of the following characters: `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`
- `(A-Z)` as a range, or any of the following characters: `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`
- `( )` a space character
- `(')` a single quote character
- `` ( -`) `` a space to backtick as a range, or any of the following characters: `` !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_ ` ``

As you can see, the last three characters `` ( -`) `` are creating a range that spans from unicode 0020 (space) to 0060 (backtick) and includes all numbers, capital letters, some special characters and... *the hyphen itself!* This is why your your string (`` asdf-'` ``) actually does match.

Unfortunately, so do many other strings containing any of those characters: `` 12ab34$!-'` ``, `#!/a b?&`, etc.

```
/^[a-zA-Z ' -`]+$/.test("asdf-'`")   // true
/^[a-zA-Z ' -`]+$/.test("!@#-456")   // true
/^[a-zA-Z ' -`]+$/.test("012#$%678") // true
/^[a-zA-Z ' -`]+$/.test("<a:5:c>")   // true
```

So, yeah, make sure to escape (or move your hyphen as described above the horizontal rule) to avoid creating a range with it!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the order of the hyphen or escape it inside of the character class.

**Note:** Inside of a character class the hyphen has **special** meaning. You can place it as the first or last character of the class. In some regular expression implementations, you can also place directly after a range. If you place the hyphen anywhere else you need to precede it with a backslash in order to add it to your character class.

> Which I want to validate...
>   i.e. alphabetic characters, hyphens, apostophes and backticks.

```
if (/^[a-z'`-]+$/i.test(this.value))
```

If you want to allow for spaces, simply add it back inside of the character class.

Comment: why would that make a difference, hyphen is not a "special character"?

Comment: Because space `-` backtick is defining a range.

Comment: bah, i see it now, newb ... "mas uno"

Comment: I tried pasting your solution on top of this http://jsfiddle.net/a4vGA/ and it didn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

```
^[a-zA-Z ' `-]+$
```

`-` defines a range. So either escape it or keep it at end to avoid forming an invalid range.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/qH1uG3/6

In your regex ``` -`` forms a range of characters between ```space`and`backtick`

https://jsfiddle.net/a4vGA/55/

Comment: Thanks @vks - your jsfiddle appears to not do any matching - is it broken?